# REST API routes URI - fetch by id or by a custom field

Tags: javascript, rest, api, model, uri

I'm building a REST API and I would like to know what are the URI best practices. I have "users" entities, that have a unique email and ID. Then I can fetch a user using this routes:

```
 GET /users/{id}
 GET /users/{email}
```

Should I expose 2 differents routes in order to fetch either by ID or EMAIL?

I looked at Github API, and they use Field identifier for some of the ressources (/:owner/:repo) and ID number for others.

Comment: I would say this is more of a use case decision - if you'd like or need the ability to fetch users based on id as well as email then just go ahead and implement both. It's slightly more work for you to implement and maintain, but gives you more flexibility.

Answer (score 0):

What I normally do with my REST API endpoints is I take the ID of the record and encode (hash) it.

A great library in node is hashids:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/hashids

For example:
GET /users/1

becomes:
GET /users/o2fXhV

It all depends on what you would like your endpoints to be. Many big companies use different naming conventions. Choose what feels right for you.

Comment: Hi, I would just like to know if there is a good practice to allow user to fetch the same ressource using 2 differents URI.
Examples: GET /users/123 - GET /users/to@to.com